# Cedet - Can't see all the prototypes of function

Tags: c++, autocomplete, semantics, cedet

I started managing my c++ projects with `CEDET` and made my configuration using Alex's Tutorial "A gentle introduction to CEDET" and almost everything is working properly.

However, although I have `semantic-idle-completion-mode` active to see the prototypes of my functions, it is not working as expected.

More precisely, when I want to call a polymorphic method or the constructor of a class with several possible constructors, the mini-buffer only shows me one possible definition.

Here is an example, I try to call one among the 3 constructors of the SrmSkeleton class.

> void createChainsFromSkel()
>   {
>
> > vector effectors = mySkeleton->getEndEffectors();
> >
> > mySkeleton = new SmrSkeleton(

The only prototype `Semantic` suggests me is

> SmrSkeleton SmrSkeleon (string _name)

However, if a use `M-x semantic-analize-current-context, this is what I get

> Context Type: #
>
> Bounds: nil
>
> Function: SmrSkeleton SmrSkeleton (string _name)
>
> ```
>       SmrSkeleton SmrSkeleton (SmrModeType _mode,SmrTransformationOrderType _rotOrder,string _name)
>      SmrSkeleton SmrSkeleton (const SmrSkeleton& _skel)
>       virtual void ~SmrSkeleton (void)
> ```
>
> Argument Index: 1
>
> Argument: void
>
> Prefix Classes: 'function
>                   'variable
>                   'type

The 3 existing constructors are listed but not suggested. And when I try to use `M-x semantic-ia-complete-symbol` emacs stops completely.

I would like to know why `CEDET` is working like this and if there is something (change my cedet configuration, redefine some variables...) I can do to fix this strange behavior.